# Android M SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, system-alert-window

As stated here: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2971 it will not be possible to ask for permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW. It refers to a system settings, allowing or disallowing these kind of windows.

Does anyone know where this setting can be located, I'm not able to find it. And, what is the default value of the setting?

Comment: The default value of `canDrawOverlays()` is `false`, IIRC. So, basically, this is now a double-opt-in, akin to configuring device administrators, input method editors, etc.

Comment: There is the `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` `Intent`, as shown in the answer on the linked-to question. The user can get to that same screen manually via Settings > Apps > Configure (the gear icon in the action bar) > "Draw over other apps".

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the other thread and deleted my comment before you replied. Thank you ;)